# SSRS multiple datasets: How to display only records that are not in both Datasets

Tags: dataset, datasource, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I'm using SSRS 2008 R2 and building a report with Report Builder 3.0. 
I need to query 2 databases, a Central one here at headquarters and a Satellite one in Australia.
They both have a table called Buyers. The satellite site just contains a smaller set of data that we will return to central at a later date.
They have the following fields; idBuyer, IdCustomer, DateRegistered
Right now I want to query all the records in the Satellite site for Customers (idCustomer) that are not already in the same table in the central datasource
I’m using a LookUp using idBuyer to join the datasets in a Tablix. Now I just want to filter for results where idCustomer from the Satellite dataset is not in the Central Dataset

Any pointers would be appreciated as I assume this would be pretty simple but I’m not getting it to work

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should do this in SQL. It would make the report a lot quicker.

```
SELCT ID FROM SATELLITE WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM CENTRAL)
```

However, that's not always possible so you can filter the Satellite db where the ID is not in the CENTRAL ID using the **InSTR**ing funtion.

For your filter, set the **Expression** to idBuyer

```
=IIF(INSTR("|" & Fields!idBuyer.Value & "|", "|" & JOIN(LookupSet(1, 1, Fields!idBuyer.Value, "CENTRAL"), "|") & "|"), 0, 1)
```

This will create a string of the IDs from CENTRAL db and look if the ID from the Sattelite DB is in it. If the ID is in the CENTRAL db, the row gets a 0 else 1. Then set the Value to 1.

[image]

The **Pipes** ( | ) is used to separate the values so it doesn't find 25 when you have 125 or 251 in the list.